# Customizing ResourceBundle file formats for getBundle()?

Tags: java, locale, resourcebundle

Is there a way to alter the file format & name formatting for a ResourceBundle? This probably sounds like a fairly pointless goal but in essence I want to change it so that instead of looking for:

```
   > baseName + "_" + language + "_" + country + ".properties"
```

It will look for:

```
   > language + "_" + country + ".specifiedformat"
```

I'm making a small program and would like to put each locale into a single file with a different file format to .properties, simply using a specific locale as the default.

I've experimented around with ResourceBundle.Control but haven't had any luck. Just for the file format part I'm trying to extend ResourceBundle & Control such that I can declare a new format. getControl is final so can't really do anything there easily.

```
   public static class MyControl extends Control {

     public static final List<String> FORMAT_MYFORMAT
          = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("java.myformat",
                                                 "java.class",
                                                 "java.properties"));

    @Override
    public List<String> getFormats(String baseName) {
        if (baseName == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
         }
         return FORMAT_MYFORMAT;
      }
    }
```

I don't know if what I'm trying is anywhere close to the mark. I can mostly get my head around the methods in `ResourceBundle` just not everything as a whole.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to overwrite `ResourceBundle.Control.newBundle(...)` too, in the default implementation it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if format is not either `java.class` or `java.properties`.